# Record google meet audio using puppeteerr

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, puppeteer

I am trying to record a google meet using puppeteer, so far I am able to join the meet as a bot and record the video. But I am not able to record the audio, I tried few packages like puppeteer-screen-recorder, but it is creating an empty file for audio.
Here is my script code
Pls change the meeting URL to replicate and test

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
import { executablePath } from 'puppeteer';
import fs from 'fs';
import AudioRecorder from 'node-audiorecorder';
import * as PuppeteerScreenRecorder from 'puppeteer-screen-recorder'
import RecordRTC from 'recordrtc';

import { getStream } from "puppeteer-stream";

const file = fs.createWriteStream("./test.webm");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    devtools: false,
    args: [
      "--window-size=1920,1080",
      "--window-position=1921,0",
      "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required",
    ],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--mute-audio"],
    executablePath: executablePath(),
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();
  const context = browser.defaultBrowserContext();

  await context.overridePermissions(
    "https://meet.google.com/", ["microphone", "camera", "notifications"]
  );

  // going to Meet after signing in
  await page.waitForTimeout(2500);
  await page.goto('https://meet.google.com/cmp-zzwo-adb' + '?hl=en', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    timeout: 10000,
  });

  await navigationPromise;

  await page.waitForSelector('input[aria-label="Your name"]', {
    visible: true,
    timeout: 50000,
    hidden: false,
  });

  // turn off cam using Ctrl+E
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
  await page.keyboard.press('KeyE');
  await page.keyboard.up('ControlLeft');
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

  //turn off mic using Ctrl+D
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
  await page.keyboard.down('ControlLeft');
  await page.keyboard.press('KeyD');
  await page.keyboard.up('ControlLeft');
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

  //click on input field to enter name
  await page.click(`input[aria-label="Your name"]`);

  //enter name
  await page.type(`input[aria-label="Your name"]`, 'Bot');

  //click on ask to join button
  await page.click(
    `button[class="VfPpkd-LgbsSe VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf nCP5yc AjY5Oe DuMIQc LQeN7 jEvJdc QJgqC"]`
  );

  const stream = await getStream(page, { audio: true, mimeType: "audio/mp3" });
  console.log("recording");

  stream.pipe(file);
  // setTimeout(async () => {
  //   await stream.destroy();
  //   file.close();
  //   console.log("finished");
  // }, 1000 * 30);


  const recorder = new PuppeteerScreenRecorder.PuppeteerScreenRecorder(page);
  await recorder.start('./report/video/simple.webm'); // supports extension - mp4, avi, webm and mov

  // const devices = await page.evaluate(() =>
  //   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
  //     { audio: true }
  //   )
  // )

  // let x = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});

  // console.log(x, "Available devices");
  // navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  //   video: false,
  //   audio: true
  // }).then(async function (stream) {
  //   let recorder = RecordRTC(stream, {
  //     type: 'audio'
  //   });
  //   recorder.startRecording();

  //   const sleep = m => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, m));
  //   await sleep(3000);

  //   recorder.stopRecording(function () {
  //     let blob = recorder.getBlob();
  //     invokeSaveAsDialog(blob);
  //   });
  // });


  setTimeout(async () => {
    await recorder.stop();
    await stream.destroy();
    file.close();
    console.log("finished");
    await browser.close();
  }, 15000)

})();
```

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "own",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-audiorecorder": "^3.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^19.6.3",
    "puppeteer-extra": "^3.3.4",
    "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.11.1",
    "puppeteer-screen-recorder": "^2.1.2",
    "puppeteer-stream": "^2.1.4",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.2",
    "screencap": "^1.0.0",
    "ws": "^8.12.1"
  }
}
```

I tried using different available packages of puppeteer but it's creating an empty file only for audio. I was able to record the video with different packages but audio is not capturing. I want to record the audio of meeting attendees.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are very close to solving this using `puppeteer-stream`. They have an example using `puppeteer-extra` [here](https://github.com/SamuelScheit/puppeteer-stream/blob/main/examples/puppeteer-extra.js), you need to change:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  defaultViewport: null,
  devtools: false,
  args: [
    "--window-size=1920,1080",
    "--window-position=1921,0",
    "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required",
  ],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--mute-audio"],
  executablePath: executablePath(),
});
```

for

```js
const browser = await launch(puppeteer, {
  headless: false,
  defaultViewport: null,
  devtools: false,
  args: [
    "--window-size=1920,1080",
    "--window-position=1921,0",
    "--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required",
  ],
  ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--mute-audio"],
  executablePath: executablePath(),
});
```

where `launch` is imported from `puppeteer-stream`.